# ostream_iterator don't skip space

Tags: c++, string

I have such code, I am puzzled why the spaces in the string is not trimmed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>  //T type of stream element
void trimspace2(std::string str) //user istream_iterator  suppose it's a number string
{
  istringstream iss(str),ise("");
  ostringstream oss(str);
  copy(istream_iterator<T>(iss),istream_iterator<T>(ise),ostream_iterator<T>(oss," "));
  cout << str << endl;
}

int main() 
{
  std::string str = " 20 30    100  ";
  trimspace2<int>(str);
  return 0;
}
```

output is

```
" 20 30    100  "
```

the same as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are outputting `str`, your input parameter, at the end of your function. Change the last line to:

```
cout << oss.str() << endl;
```

Oh, and you should not use `str` to construct `oss`:

```
ostringstream oss;
```

Base on your comment below, I think you want something like:

```
template <typename T>
void trimspace2(std::string &str)
{
    istringstream iss(str);
    ostringstream oss;
    copy(istream_iterator<T>(iss),istream_iterator<T>(),ostream_iterator<T>(oss," "));
    str = oss.str();
}
```

Comment: But I mean to modify str in place.

Comment: @JackChin: You pass `str` by value so you can't modify the caller's variable. Try changing the parameter to a reference, `std:string &str`, and assigning a new value in your function, `str = oss.str()`